# How to set up OpenSearch in Drupal?

Tags: 7, search

I would like to set up [OpenSearch](http://www.opensearch.org/Home) so it works in Drupal 7 so the search experience can be integrated with the user browser the way it is done on drupal.stackexchange.com.

I found the following contrib modules (none ported for D7):

- http://drupal.org/project/opensearchplugin - D5, D6
- http://drupal.org/project/opensearch - D6
- http://drupal.org/project/opensearch_aggregator - D5, D6

What is the current solution for this for D7 ?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer on this?

Answer (score 2):

From looking at these three modules closer, I see that only the opensearch module has a 7.x branch: https://drupal.org/node/74142/release.  You could try using that branch, but it probably not ready for a production system.

It looks like [Kiam](https://drupal.org/user/54793) is the module author you may be able to contact him to find out if he is planning to complete the Drupal 7 version.